# Rails 3 correctly using dynamic columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user model that has a joined column which I am trying to reference as an additional_column when calling the views/user/_showcase.html.erb partial

For the complete back story see [Rails 3 noob questions using partials correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10116857) as I was asked to split the questions into two posts.

views/users/_showcase.html.erb

```
<td><img src="<%= user.avatar_url(32) %>" /></td>
<td><%= user.username%></td>    
<% additional_columns.each do |column| %>
    <td><%= user[column]%></td>
<% end %>
```

Here is how I implemented the computed column on my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper

  ... snip ...

  # Get the last 10 users who made Karmunity accounts
  scope :get_newest_users , order("created_at desc").limit(10);

  # Get 10 users with the highest karma score
  scope :get_highest_rated_user, order("karma_score desc").limit(10);

  scope :avatar_url
  scope :joined

  # get the dated they joined in time ago format  
  def joined
    time_ago_in_words(self.created_at)
  end

  # Get the gravatar image url 
  def avatar_url (size=nil)

    query_string = '';

    unless size.nil?
      query_string = 's=' + size.to_s  
    end

    "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + Digest::MD5.hexdigest(self.email.strip.downcase) + "?#{query_string}"
  end
end
```

However, when I execute this code, user.avatar_url, and if I manually type user.joined it works fine but the dynamic column (I'm assuming it behaves like user[:joined]) returns an empty string. I'm sure that I'm doing something dumb here but I don't know how to dynamically get computed/formatted model values.

For the sake of completeness, this is my call to the partial

```
<%= render :partial => 'users/showcase', :locals => { :id => 'newest_users', :title => 'Newest Users', :users => @newest_users, :additional_columns => [:affiliation,:joined]} %>
```

I'd appreciate any direction as this is my first rails app and I'm not really sure what kind of questions I should be asking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

so I stumbled on a solution, but i have no idea if this is a good implementation

```
<% users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="<%= user.avatar_url(32) %>" /></td>
        <td><%= user.username%></td>
        <% additional_columns.each do |column| %>
            <td><%= user.send(column)%></td>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```